# When I make a change in a user (clicking the edit tab) and save the change, the field remains the same

Tags: users

I go to edit (registered as admin or as the user) to make a change in the user and then I make the change in a field and click save. The message says that my change has been saved but then I scroll down and the field remains the same.

Does anybody know what the problem might be? I don't get any error messages.

My drupal version is 7.26 and I am having the problem on a number field (called telephone number), an address field, a URL field, a text field, an image field (I try deleting a photo and it appears again after saving). Basically, all the fields except for username and email address.

Also, if I fill in the registration form (as an anonymous user) a new account is created but only the compulsory fields are filled. If I fill any field that is not compulsory the data is lost. The field later appears as empty in the user's account.

If I try to edit content I do not have any problems. It works fine.

I am working on localhost and not connected to a web server.

I have checked in /admin/reports/dblog and there is nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Few things to check: 1. Try to replicate the same issue on a clean install; 2. Post some details about the dev environment you're working in (win/lin/osx); 3. Which modules are you using? Do you have any non-standard settings for user registration/update?; 4. Any custom modules?; 5. Any errors in the web server error log?

Comment: 1. I have tried 1 and the problem remains. 2. I am working with osx. 3. For user registration I am using conditional fields and field validation. Also, masquerade (related with users). I don't know where I can find the user registration/update settings but I haven't touched anything. 4. No custom modules. 5. I am not using a web server.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not using a web server"?

Comment: I mean the site is not online. I am just using localhost for everything. I am not connected to anything online.

Comment: Even in that case you are using a web server, which runs locally :) If you're on OSX, you are probably using MAMP, meaning you are on Apache. Check error logs found in: Applications -> MAMP -> logs -> `apache_error.log` and `php_error.log`.

Comment: In `apache_error.log` I get this a lot -> `[error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store`                      In `php_error.log` I get this -> `PHP Strict Standards: Non-static method sqlite::getDbVersion() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Applications/MAMP/bin/SQLiteManager/include/SQLiteAutoConnect.class.php on line 12`. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: Doesn't really make that much sense; I would try reinstalling the MAMP to be honest. This could be some silly bug that would take a lot of time to figure out.

Comment: The problem was a bug in the conditional fields module. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: No problem. Even if it was misconfiguration on your end, post your solution as an answer in case someone else ends up in the same situation.